# QR code best approach for POST request from REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, qr-code

I'm setting up a website that will be mobile focused and one of the features I wan't to implement is users to be able to log an entry by just scanning a QR code.

For what I read is not really possible to make a POST request directly from a QR code, so I was thinking  in two different options:

**1. Make a GET request and then redirect that inside my server to a POST route in my routes.**

So the URL would be something like https://example.com/user/resources/someresourceid123/logs/new and then this would create a POST request to https://example.com/user/resources/someresourceid123/logs/ and create the new entry to then send a response to the user but I'm not really sure this is the best approach or if it's possible at all.

My POST request only requires the resourceid which I should be able to get from req.params and the userid which I get from my req.user.

**2. Do my logic and log the entry to my DB using the GET request to https://example.com/user/resources/someresourceid123/logs/new.**

This would mean that my controller for that request will do everything needed from the GET request without having to make an additional POST request afterwards. I should be able to get both the resourceid and userid from the req object but not sure if being a GET request limits what I can do with it.

If any of those are possible, which would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd propose to go with a second option simply for the sake of performance. But you need to make sure your requests are not cached by any proxy, which is usually the case with GET requests.

Comment: I think it does make sense. Any recommendation on how to prevent those requests from being cached? Also, what would the implications be if that happens?

Comment: Simply adding `Cache-Control: no-cache` header should do the trick. You can add it only to your tracking endpoint, so that it doesn't change behavior for other GET requests.